# Running a C++ program from Django

Tags: python, c++, django

I have a Django web application where a user can upload a file. I have a C++ program that should read the uploaded file, do some processing and create a new output file. I then want to allow the user to download this output file from the Django web application.

I am having problem figuring out how to **send the path of the uploaded file to the C++ Program** and then **running the C++ program from within Django**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess in pyhton to run your app by full path.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/your-app/app', '/input/file/path'])
```